# Jenkins :: Dynamic String Parameter

Tags: jenkins, parameters

I have a parameterized project with one Choice Parameter `param1` and a regular String Parameter `param2` with a default value.
I would like to know how to dynamically change the default value of `param2` according to `param1` selection?

I heard about **Active Choices Plugin** and it looks good but the plugin is no longer available in the Jenkins update center because of vulnerability issue...

Is there something equivalent ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen any alternative. The [Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) depends on the [Scriptler Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Scriptler+Plugin), which was pulled for security reasons. You can, at your own risk, still install and use these plugins, ignoring the security concerns (see top of the Scriptler Plugin page), by bypassing the update center like this:

1. **Active Choices Plugin**: Get the [1.5.3 hpi](https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/org/biouno/uno-choice/1.5.3/uno-choice-1.5.3.hpi) from https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/org/biouno/uno-choice/ (the Jenkins project Maven repository) and [upload it to jenkins per the advanced plugin installation instructions](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/#advanced-installation).
2. **Scriptler Plugin**: Get the [2.9 hpi](https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/scriptler/2.9/scriptler-2.9.hpi) from https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/scriptler/2.9/ and [upload it to jenkins per the advanced plugin installation instructions](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/#advanced-installation).

This info was had from the comments at the bottom of the [Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) page. I suspect any updates or announcements of a new secure version will land there first, though there is also [this closed "bug"](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43663).