# Uno choice plugin in jenkins doesn't existe any more?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to build a job but i have this error:

Processing DSL script jenkinsFile Warning: (jenkinsFile, line 128)   activeChoiceParam is deprecated Warning: (jenkinsFile, line 128)    version 1.2 or later of plugin 'uno-choice' needs to be installed    Warning: (jenkinsFile, line 136) activeChoiceReactiveParam is    deprecated Warning: (jenkinsFile, line 136) version 1.2 or later of  plugin 'uno-choice' needs to be installed Warning: (jenkinsFile, line    145) activeChoiceReactiveParam is deprecated Warning: (jenkinsFile,    line 145) version 1.2 or later of plugin 'uno-choice' needs to be    installed Warning: (jenkinsFile, line 128) activeChoiceParam is    deprecated Warning: (jenkinsFile, line 128) version 1.2 or later of    plugin 'uno-choice' needs to be installed Warning: (jenkinsFile, line    136) activeChoiceReactiveParam is deprecated Warning: (jenkinsFile,    line 136) version 1.2 or later of plugin 'uno-choice' needs to be    installed Warning: (jenkinsFile, line 145) activeChoiceReactiveParam is deprecated

i searched in plugins but i can't find uno choice plugin !!
it worked before, i just face this error today !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the [Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) was pulled out of the update center for security reasons.

The answer at [Jenkins :: Dynamic String Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357736/jenkins-dynamic-string-parameter/44361220#44361220) describes how to install it anyway if you hate security.